# How open tab in Espresso

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-espresso

How can i open tab in Espresso test? I  tried to do `Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.practice_results_tab)).perform(ViewActions.click());`, but that doesn't working. In that code i opened Layout of this tab.
There is the XML file:

```
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/practice_tabHost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/practice_settings_tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/practice_results_tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

What ID should I use to open tab?

Error in logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target     view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
Target view: "LinearLayout{id=2131296384, res-name=practice_results_tab, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace of that exception? With PerformExceptions, the "Caused by" part is the most important.

Comment: @haffax add full stack trace.

Comment: The error says that your target view is a linear layout. I'd start by double checking your id in the xml. Is there any text on your tab? Could you reference your view with "onView(withText('string here'))"?

Comment: @Maxwell add xml file. I don't understand how in basics i should open tabs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Completed Code

*You really need to add code for us to give a proper answer. I'm guessing here that you used a TabHost and TabWidget in the way this example does: https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-tabhost-and-tabwidget/*

I've created a sample project at https://github.com/hanscappelle/SO-25016397

Your Activity could then look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // setNewTab(context, tabHost, tag, title, icon, contentID);
        this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab1", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.ic_tab_settings, R.id.practice_settings_tab);
        this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab2", R.string.textTabTitle2, R.drawable.ic_tab_results, R.id.practice_results_tab);

    }

    private void setNewTab(Context context, TabHost tabHost, String tag, int title, int icon, int contentID ){
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        String titleString = getString(title);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(titleString, context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on));
        tabSpec.setContent(contentID);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
}
```

I found another code example at https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/android-styling-the-tabs-in-a-tabwidget/ with a helper method that injects an `ImageView` for the tabs.

```
private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(title);
        return view;
    }
```

Now it gets interesting cause this way we can easily set an ID or a tag on these injected `View` objects and use these in Espresso.

## A solution: Tag the view

If you adapt that helper to accept a tag for each view helper code will look something like this:

```
private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon, int viewId, String viewTag) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        tv.setText(title);
        tv.setTag(viewTag);
        return view;
    }
```

*If you use only icons you can set the ID on the ImageView also.*

And the Espresso code to click these tabs:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withTagValue(Matchers.is((Object)"tab1"))).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

## Alternative Solution: using View IDs

If you go for IDs you need these IDs to be defined somewhere. Use a simple Android resource file with some ID definitions.

The view ID resource file, named /values/ids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tab1" type="id" />
</resources>
```

The adapted helper:

```
private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon, int viewId, String viewTag) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    iv.setImageResource(icon);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    tv.setText(title);
    tv.setId(viewId);
    return view;
}
```

*If you use only icons you can set the ID on the ImageView also.*

And the Espresso code to click these tabs:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.tab1)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

## About TabHosts in general

Why did you use this TabHost in the first place? Note that this class is deprecated by now. A [ViewPager with tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) or [the ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) might be better options depending on your use case.

## Use the ViewHierarchy tool

In cases like this the first problem is often to find the proper view. For this use the **View Hierarchy** tool. It's part of the android SDK and lives in the tools directory.

You can start it from command line like this:

```
cd ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION/tools
hierarchyviewer
```

Or use **Android Studio** menu: Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor. Then open the Hierarchy View perspective from the menu in the device monitor: Window > Open Perspective > Hierarchy View .

*I prefer the first option just because the Device Monitor does way too much for our intentions.*

Now use the Layout View in combination with the View Properties view to find the ID and tags of the view you want.

Some instructions on this tool: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Comment: Is this solution compatible with current ViewPager api?

Answer (score 3):

the only thing that works for me is:

```
public void clickOnTab(String tabText) {    
    Matcher<View> matcher = allOf(withText(tabText),
                                  isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.ll_tab_container)));
    onView(matcher).perform(click());    
}
```

where `ll_tab_container` is the linearlayout for my custom tab layout.  and if you had a tab called "shopping" then you would pass that as the tabText.

Comment: Exactly no need to tag views. I think this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

onView(withText("Your tab label")).perform(click())

Comment: This is the simplest one!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to set a tag on your tab text without using a custom indicator method. You do this by accessing the tab's `TextView` after it has been created.

Using the `MainActivity` from hcpl's example code, that would look something like this:

```
public MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // setNewTab(context, tabHost, tag, title, icon, contentID);
        this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab1", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.ic_tab_settings, R.id.practice_settings_tab);
        this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab2", R.string.textTabTitle2, R.drawable.ic_tab_results, R.id.practice_results_tab);

        // Set custom tag on first tab
        View tabView1 = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0);
        TextView tabView1Text = (TextView) signUpTabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        signUpTextTab.setTag("TAG_TAB_ONE");

        // Set custom tag on second tab
        View tabView2 = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1);
        TextView tabView1Text = (TextView) signUpTabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        signUpTextTab.setTag("TAG_TAB_TWO");
    }
}
```

Then in your Espresso test, you could access the tabs like this:

```
onView(withTagValue(Matchers.is((Object)"TAG_TAB_TWO"))).perform(click());
```