# How to perform click tab using android espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I'm trying to click tab using espresso and always get error.

I have layout as below, and try to click tab2 :

```
 <TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/object_response"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"
                        android:textSize="16sp">
                    </TextView>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/json_response"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"
                        android:textSize="16sp">
                    </TextView>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And this is my code in activity class :

```
   TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
   host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.object));
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.object));
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.json));
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.json));
    host.addTab(spec);
```

I have tried to follow suggestion in this link : [How open tab in espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016397/how-open-tab-in-espresso) , but still getting error for both using id and tag value.

Espresso code using ID :

```
onView(withId(R.id.tab2)).perform(click());
```

Error received :

> > android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id:
> >     com.greenwavesystems.axon.lib.testapp:id/tab2'.
>
> android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1959)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints: at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to
>   the user. Target view: "LinearLayout{id=2131558557, res-name=tab2,
>   visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0,
>   y=0.0, child-count=1}" at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:138)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Espresso code using tag value :

```
onView(withTagValue(is((Object)"Json"))).perform(click());
```

Error received :

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: with tag value: is "Json"

I tried also suggestion in this [blog](http://qiita.com/teracy/items/20c5fd5c28075f35103f) and still no luck.

Below this my code :

```
 public static Matcher<View> TabMatcher(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int index) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                if (!(view.getParent() instanceof TabHost)) {
                    return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
                }
                TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) view.getParent();
                return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent())
                        && tabHost.getTabContentView().getChildCount() > index &&
                        tabHost.getTabContentView().getChildAt(index) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {

            }
        };
    }

onView(TabMatcher(withId(R.id.tabHost), 1)).perform(click());
```

No error received but tab2 still not perform click.

Kindly advise which part that I'm missing and really appreaciate for any kind help.

Comment: When you run your test, do you see your tab2 on the screen?

Comment: Hi, yes I see my tab2 on the screen but it not open (showing) when I perform click.

Comment: Seems this solution could be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016397/how-open-tab-in-espresso